# can't change background color in theme Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to define a custom theme using material UI and defining a `default` background colour for it. But the changes are not taking effect while other `pallete` options are working. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? As far as I can tell this is the way to change the colour.

Here's my code

`theme.ts`

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import {red} from '@mui/material/colors';
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: '#FFD600',
      paper: '#FFD600',
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

my entry file

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material/styles"
import theme from '../theme'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

EDIT: It seems to be changing the background for the components I have used with material-UI but not for other components I may define.
e.g. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CudFx.jpg). I used the card component of MUI and the background was changed but I need it to change the background colour of the whole page

EDIT2: The component one worked because I defined paper colour, but I still cant get `default` to work

Comment: Isn't default color called main, so instead default: '#FFD600', you should have main: '#FFD600'

Comment: No, that's for `primary`, `secondary` colours. Not for `background` property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the reason it's still not working is that we need to import `CssBaseline` for it to work. `CssBaseline` implements `background.default` color according to the doc.

Here's how it'll work

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material/styles"
import theme from '../theme'
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material/';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Still weird how the `paper` property works but for `default` you need to import additional dependencies